# Use JOIN after WHERE EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
 INSERT INTO user_data(login_id, date) 
                SELECT * FROM(VALUES ( 
        (SELECT id as login_id FROM user WHERE uuid = '32bfd326-2288'), 'now()'::timestamp)) x
                WHERE EXISTS 
    ((SELECT "isValid" FROM valida_data WHERE login_id = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE uuid = '32bfd326-2288') AND "isProgramPaused" IS FALSE))
```

What I need is to join `user` table to prevent this select `SELECT id FROM user WHERE uuid = '32bfd326-2288'`

As output I need something like:

```
  INSERT INTO user_data(login_id, date) 
                    SELECT * FROM(VALUES ( 
            user.id as login_id, 'now()'::timestamp)) x
                    WHERE EXISTS 
        ((SELECT "isValid" FROM valida_data WHERE login_id = user.id AND "isProgramPaused" IS FALSE))
JOIN user ON uuid = '32bfd326-2288'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: *As output I need* You've not shown any *output*. You've shown an SQL INSERT statement. Please provide sample data and a more clear description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to avoid to call twice SELECT id FROM user WHERE uuid = '32bfd326-2288' in query